# Edge browser sets zoom level on website, when first visiting the site

Tags: browser-compatibility

We've just launched a website based on the Total Theme:
https://themeforest.net/item/total-responsive-multipurpose-wordpress-theme/6339019

The site is one among many websites we've build using this theme, but the only one that is acting up in the Edge browser.

Go to : Cricket.dk and have a look. (in Edge).

For some, the issue is that the zoom is above 100% eg. 195%  - the website looks fine though, since it does what you'd expect, fill out the entire browserwindow.

For others - the zoom is 100% - making the website very small.

Answer (score 0):

Edge browser (and Chrome and Firefox too), are using the Windows screen size and display ratio to render. I have Lenovo Yoga 2 Pro laptop with a screen resolution of 3200x1800. If I set display ratio to 100%, then browser displays website smaller (website is 1200px wide, for instance, and the rest to 3200 is empty). But, if I set the ratio to 200%, it looks OK.

This is similar to iOS Retina display, but on the desktop and in Windows. It all comes to Windows settings for display.

Current responsive website trends usually require proper Viewport set for the website, and this is the meta tag (for the page HEAD) that is most common for the responsive websites:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
```

Comment: So what parameter would I need to set in Meta ?

Comment: There is nothing you can set. That display ratio is set through the Windows display settings, it is on operating system level.

Comment: It's wired, since we have multiple sites that run the same way - this one is the only one doing this.

Some people are suggesting to define Viewport in Meta tags.

Comment: That is usually set, and I have rarely seen any new WordPress theme that doesn't have it, so I have not suggested that. But, that is kind of a requirement for the responsive website to work. I have updated my answer and added viewport tag I use for my websites.